# What is the difference between AssemblyRef and TypeRef in assesmbly metadata in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

If `TypeRef` and `AssemblyRef` token describe external types reference list then what is the difference between them?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: What makes you say that `AssemblyRef` describes a *type*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you Damien,I got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both are file tables:

TypeRef: Each row represents an imported class, its namespace, and the assembly which contains it.

AssemblyRef: Each row represents an external assembly.